# Comparing occurences in time series

Tags: statistics, time-series

I have several time series.  Series 1 might have an average of 55, series 2 might have an average of 20, and so on.  Each series sticks close to its average.

Occasionally, the value of a series will change significantly (wrt the average).  Maybe from 55 to 115, for example.  Sometimes the value in the adjacent series (series 2, for the case of series 1) will change significantly (wrt its average) at the same time.  Sometimes it won't.

I'm looking for a way to determine when adjacent series tend to change at the same time.  I'm not worried about the numbers (55 to 115, 20 to x), but rather I'm looking to determine if they tend to change at the same time.  Two adjacent series will either change at the same time always (they're related), or not very often (due to just chance).

What's a good tool for this?

Answer (score 1):

The concepts you are looking for are called cross-correlation and cross-covariance.

Comment: I've used Pearson correlation with different threshold values and it didn't seem to work well.  It identified some, but not a majority, of patterns.  I think the issue is that the amount of change in one time series is not proportional to the change in the adjacent.  I think it's best to consider them both "on" or "off" at each time, instead of the actual value.  (on being greater than some threshold wrt the avg)

Comment: I don't think that the Pearson correlation is the right tool for your problem. If you look for cross-correlation, you will see that it involves a "lag" that is absent from the Pearson correlation.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out

Comment: I am supposing the patterns you visually identified are not being captured by the Pearson correlation because they are not separated by a lag equal to the length of the timeseries. If your difficulty persists after reading about cross-correlation, please write again given a short numerical example of the problem.